# How to run cache s3 session generated by MFA

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to write python script to access s3 objects.
I am able to get access to s3 (using assume role, boto3 and MFA is enabled on my account)

My question is do i need to enter MFA token every single time i run the script? Is it possible to cache session for selected duration and use when running the script for the second time?

At the moment i have created a setup class in Test suite

```
import unittest
import boto3


class TestS3Buckets():

    s3 = None


@classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        credentials = get_role_credentials(
            "arn:aws:iam::123456:role/admin-assume",
            "test-env",
            "arn:aws:iam::111111111:mfa/test@test.com",
            "MFA token"
            )
        session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id=credentials["Credentials"]["AccessKeyId"],
            aws_secret_access_key=credentials["Credentials"]["SecretAccessKey"],
            aws_session_token=credentials["Credentials"]["SessionToken"]
        )
        cls.s3 = session.client('s3')
```

Is there a way i can ignore MFA token while running the script for the second time ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Generally for unit tests you do not actually call external services, instead mocking the API calls. The `moto` library helps with this specifically for AWS api call.

Comment: If `get_role_credentials` is doing `assume_role`, the API call has a duration or expiration param.

Comment: i am actually testing API service, so can't mock API calls